# java.lang.NullPointerException at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy handleRenderException

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2, prettyfaces

The code which is working earlier stops working when I started using @ViewScoped along with f:metadata, f:viewParam for editing an item in a datatable.

I am using JSF-2.2 with Prettyfaces-2.0.12.Final

Below are similar questions but there are no answers:

[java.lang.NullPointerException at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy$MethodRetargetHandlerManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23452491/java-lang-nullpointerexception-at-com-sun-faces-application-view-faceletviewhand)

[com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy handleRenderException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26672990/com-sun-faces-application-view-faceletviewhandlingstrategy-handlerenderexception)

Find the below complete stack trace:

```
com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy handleRenderException
SEVERE: Error Rendering View[/restricted/professional_details.xhtml]
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.net.URLEncoder.encode(URLEncoder.java:205)
    at com.sun.faces.context.UrlBuilder.addValuesToParameter(UrlBuilder.java:318)
    at com.sun.faces.context.UrlBuilder.addParameters(UrlBuilder.java:127)
    at com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextImpl.encodeBookmarkableURL(ExternalContextImpl.java:1055)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.getBookmarkableURL(MultiViewHandler.java:407)
    at org.ocpsoft.rewrite.faces.RewriteViewHandler.getBookmarkableURL(RewriteViewHandler.java:164)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.OutcomeTargetRenderer.getEncodedTargetURL(OutcomeTargetRenderer.java:194)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.OutcomeTargetLinkRenderer.renderAsActive(OutcomeTargetLinkRenderer.java:158)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.OutcomeTargetLinkRenderer.encodeBegin(OutcomeTargetLinkRenderer.java:96)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeBegin(UIComponentBase.java:864)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1854)
    at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:176)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:889)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1856)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:456)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:133)
    at org.ocpsoft.rewrite.faces.RewriteViewHandler.renderView(RewriteViewHandler.java:186)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.ocpsoft.rewrite.servlet.RewriteFilter.doFilter(RewriteFilter.java:205)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:487)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:412)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)
    at org.ocpsoft.rewrite.servlet.impl.HttpRewriteResultHandler.handleResult(HttpRewriteResultHandler.java:41)
    at org.ocpsoft.rewrite.servlet.RewriteFilter.rewrite(RewriteFilter.java:268)
    at org.ocpsoft.rewrite.servlet.RewriteFilter.doFilter(RewriteFilter.java:188)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at com.pe.application.PEFilter.doFilter(PEFilter.java:64)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:1
23)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

professional_details.xhtml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough"
    xmlns:pf="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>
</h:head>
<h:body>

    <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="admin.css" />
    <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="font.css" />
    <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="font-awesome.css" />
    <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="jquery-ui.css" />

    <h:outputScript library="js" name="jquery.min.js" target="head" />
    <h:outputScript library="js" name="jquery-ui.min.js" target="head" />
    <h:outputScript library="js" name="bootstrap.js" target="head" />
    <h:outputScript library="js" name="bootstrap-modal.js" target="head" />
    <h:outputScript library="js" name="script.js" target="head" />
    <h:outputScript library="js" name="signup.js" target="head" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
        //For calendar
        $(function() {
            $(".datepicker").datepicker({

                showOtherMonths : true,
                selectOtherMonths : true,
                showButtonPanel : true,
                changeMonth : true,
                changeYear : true,
                yearRange : '1980:2014',
                dateFormat : 'mm/dd/yy',
                showWeek : true
            });
        });
    </script>

    <ui:include src="../includes/header.xhtml" />
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <f:metadata>
            <f:viewParam name="id"
                value="#{professionalDetailsManagedBean.professionalBean}"
                converter="#{professionalConverter}"
                converterMessage="Unknown professional please use a link from within the system."
                required="true"
                requiredMessage="Bad request, please use a link from within the system." />
        </f:metadata>

        <h:messages />

        <!-- <h:form enctype="multipart/form-data"> -->
        <h:form id="include">
            <ui:include src="../includes/adminSideMenu.xhtml" />
        </h:form>
        <section class="row-fluid">
        <div role="main" class="span10">
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <section role="main" class="span12"> <!-- <div class="span10"> -->
                <h1>
                    #{professionalDetailsManagedBean.professionalBean.professionalName}</h1>
                <br></br>
                <h:form id="profTabs">
                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" style="font-size: 15px;">
                        <li class="active"><h:link
                                outcome="pretty:professionalDetails" value="Profile">
                                <f:param name="professionalName"
                                    value="#{professionalDetailsManagedBean.professionalBean.professionalName}" />
                                <f:param name="id"
                                    value="#{professionalDetailsManagedBean.professionalBean.professionalId}" />
                            </h:link></li>
                        <li><h:link outcome="pretty:professionalInvestments"
                                value="Investments">
                                <f:param name="professionalName"
                                    value="#{professionalDetailsManagedBean.professionalBean.professionalName}" />
                                <f:param name="professionalInvestements"
                                    value="#{professionalDetailsManagedBean.professionalBean.professionalId}" />
                            </h:link></li>
                        <li><h:link outcome="pretty:professionalInvestedFunds"
                                value="Invested Funds">
                                <f:param name="professionalName"
                                    value="#{professionalDetailsManagedBean.professionalBean.professionalName}" />
                                <f:param name="professionalInvestedFunds"
                                    value="#{professionalDetailsManagedBean.professionalBean.professionalId}" />
                            </h:link></li>
                    </ul>
                </h:form> <h:form id="profData" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <div class="row-fluid">
                        <div class="span10"></div>
                        <div class="span2 pull-right">
                            <h:graphicImage
                                value="/image?id=#{professionalDetailsManagedBean.professionalBean.professionalId}%26type=Professional" />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row-fluid">
                        <div class="span9">
                            <div class="span6">
                                <div class="control-group">
                                    <h6>Name</h6>
                                    <div class="controls">
                                        <h:messages showDetail="false" showSummary="true" />
                                        <h:inputText id="inputName"
                                            value="#{professionalDetailsManagedBean.professionalBean.professionalName}"
                                            required="true">
                                            <f:ajax listener="#{professionalManagedBean.duplicateCheck}"
                                                render="error" />
                                            <f:passThroughAttribute name="placeholder"
                                                value="Please provide Name..." />
                                            <f:passThroughAttribute name="required" value="true" />
                                        </h:inputText>
                                        <h:outputText id="error"
                                            value="#{professionalManagedBean.result}"
                                            style="margin-left: 0px; color: red;" />
                                        <div class="error" style="margin-left: 0px; color: red;"
                                            id="inputNameError" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="control-group">
                                    <h6>Designation</h6>
                                    <div class="controls">
                                        <h:inputText id="designation"
                                            value="#{professionalDetailsManagedBean.professionalBean.designation}">
                                        </h:inputText>
                                        <div class="error" style="margin-left: 0px; color: red;"
                                            id="designationError" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="control-group">
                                    <h6>Firm Name</h6>
                                    <div class="controls">
                                        <pf:autoComplete
                                            value="#{autoCompleteManagedBean.testFieldBean}"
                                            p:placeholder="Firm Name"
                                            completeMethod="#{autoCompleteManagedBean.firmsCompaniesAutoComplete}"
                                            var="p" itemLabel="#{p.name}" minQueryLength="3"
                                            style="position: inherit;" id="suggestionBoxFirmName">
                                        </pf:autoComplete>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="control-group">
                                    <h6>Email ID</h6>
                                    <div class="controls">
                                        <h:inputText id="emailId"
                                            value="#{professionalDetailsManagedBean.professionalBean.emailId}">
                                        </h:inputText>
                                        <div class="error" style="margin-left: 0px; color: red;"
                                            id="emailError"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="control-group">
                                    <h6>Phone Number</h6>
                                    <div class="controls">
                                        <h:inputText type="text" id="phoneNumber"
                                            p:placeholder="+001 5689996544" name="email"
                                            value="#{professionalDetailsManagedBean.professionalBean.phone}">
                                        </h:inputText>
                                        <div class="error" style="margin-left: 0px; color: red;"
                                            id="phoneError"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="span6">
                                <div class="control-group">
                                    <h6>Join Date</h6>
                                    <div class="controls">
                                        <h:inputText type="text" styleClass="datepicker"
                                            value="#{professionalDetailsManagedBean.professionalBean.joinDate}"
                                            id="inputJoined" readonly="#{facesContext.renderResponse}">
                                        </h:inputText>
                                        <div class="error" style="margin-left: 0px; color: red;"
                                            id="inputJoinedError"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="control-group">
                                    <h6>Exit Date</h6>
                                    <div class="controls">
                                        <h:inputText type="text" styleClass="datepicker"
                                            value="#{professionalDetailsManagedBean.professionalBean.exitDate}"
                                            id="inputLeaved" readonly="#{facesContext.renderResponse}">
                                        </h:inputText>
                                        <div class="error" style="margin-left: 0px; color: red;"
                                            id="inputLeavedError"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="control-group">
                                    <h6>Rank</h6>
                                    <div class="controls">
                                        <h:selectOneMenu
                                            value="#{professionalDetailsManagedBean.professionalBean.rank}">
                                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="0" itemValue="0" />
                                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="1" itemValue="1" />
                                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="2" itemValue="2" />
                                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="3" itemValue="3" />
                                        </h:selectOneMenu>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="control-group">
                                    <h6>Office</h6>
                                    <div class="controls">
                                        <h:selectOneMenu
                                            value="#{professionalDetailsManagedBean.professionalBean.office}">
                                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="0" itemValue="0" />
                                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="1" itemValue="1" />
                                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="2" itemValue="2" />
                                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="3" itemValue="3" />
                                        </h:selectOneMenu>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="control-group">
                                    <h6>Function</h6>
                                    <div class="controls">
                                        <h:selectOneMenu
                                            value="#{professionalDetailsManagedBean.professionalBean.function}">
                                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Please Select"
                                                noSelectionOption="true" />
                                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Investment" itemValue="Investment" />
                                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Administrative"
                                                itemValue="Administrative" />
                                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Operations" itemValue="Operations" />
                                        </h:selectOneMenu>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="span3" style="margin-top: 187px;">
                            <div>
                                <div class="control-group">
                                    <div class="center">
                                        <!-- <h:graphicImage
                                            value="/image?id=#{professionalDetailsManagedBean.professionalBean.professionalId}%26type=Professional" /> -->
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="controls">
                                        <h:inputFile id="file" name="file"
                                            value="#{professionalDetailsManagedBean.professionalBean.part}"
                                            required="true" requiredMessage="File not selected"
                                            label="file" />
                                        <h:commandButton value="Upload"
                                            action="#{professionalDetailsManagedBean.uploadProfessionalImage(professionalManagedBean.professionalBean.professionalId)}" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="well" style="text-align: center">
                                <h:commandButton styleClass="btn btn-primary btn-large"
                                    value="Save Changes"
                                    action="#{professionalDetailsManagedBean.updateProfessionalDetails(professionalManagedBean.professionalBean)}"></h:commandButton>
                                <h:outputText value=" "></h:outputText>
                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-large">Cancel</a>
                            </div>
                            <h6>Is LP (Limited Partner)?</h6>
                            <label class="checkbox"> <h:selectBooleanCheckbox
                                    name="is_active"
                                    value="#{professionalDetailsManagedBean.professionalBean.isLp}" />
                                Yes
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row-fluid">
                        <div class="span9" style="margin-left: 0px">
                            <div class="control-group">
                                <h6>Bio</h6>
                                <div class="controls">
                                    <h:inputTextarea class="span13" name="biography" rows="6"
                                        id="bio">
                                    </h:inputTextarea>
                                    <div class="error" style="margin-left: 0px; color: red;"
                                        id="bioError"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row-fluid">
                                <div class="span4">
                                    <h3 class="heading">Working Experience</h3>
                                    <h4>Current :</h4>
                                    <ul>
                                        <ui:repeat var="experience"
                                            value="#{professionalDetailsManagedBean.professionalBean.professionalWorkExpMap.entrySet().toArray()}">
                                            <h:panelGroup rendered="#{experience.value.workStatus}">
                                                <li><h:commandLink styleClass="topopup3">#{experience.value.firmOrPortfolioName}
                                                    <!-- <f:ajax
                                                            listener="#{professionalManagedBean.editProfessionalWorkExperience(experience.value.experienceId, experience.value.professionalId)}" /> -->
                                                    </h:commandLink>&nbsp; <h:commandLink styleClass="btn btn-mini btn-primary">
                                                        <span class="icon-pencil"></span>
                                                    </h:commandLink>&nbsp; <h:commandLink styleClass="btn btn-mini btn-warning">
                                                        <span class="icon-close"></span>
                                                    </h:commandLink></li>
                                                <br></br>
                                            </h:panelGroup>
                                        </ui:repeat>
                                    </ul>

                                    <h4>Past :</h4>
                                    <ul>
                                        <ui:repeat var="experience"
                                            value="#{professionalDetailsManagedBean.professionalBean.professionalWorkExpMap.entrySet().toArray()}">
                                            <h:panelGroup rendered="#{!experience.value.workStatus}">
                                                <li><h:commandLink styleClass="topopup3">#{experience.value.firmOrPortfolioName}
                                                    <!-- <f:ajax
                                                            listener="#{professionalManagedBean.editProfessionalWorkExperience(experience.value.experienceId, experience.value.professionalId)}" /> -->
                                                    </h:commandLink>&nbsp; <h:commandLink styleClass="btn btn-mini btn-primary">
                                                        <span class="icon-pencil"></span>
                                                    </h:commandLink>&nbsp; <h:commandLink styleClass="btn btn-mini btn-warning">
                                                        <span class="icon-close"></span>
                                                    </h:commandLink></li>
                                            </h:panelGroup>
                                        </ui:repeat>
                                    </ul>
                                    <div>
                                        <a href="#" id="addworkexp"
                                            class="btn btn-success pull-left topopup"><i
                                            class="icon-plus"></i> Add Work Experience</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="span4">
                                    <h3 class="heading">Sectorall Focusus</h3>
                                    <h:selectManyListbox
                                        value="#{professionalDetailsManagedBean.professionalBean.sectorallFocusus}"
                                        size="8" styleClass="defaultText">
                                        <f:selectItems
                                            value="#{newFieldsManagedBean.newFieldsBean.sectorMap.entrySet()}"
                                            var="entry" itemValue="#{entry.value}"
                                            itemLabel="#{entry.value}" />
                                    </h:selectManyListbox>
                                </div>

                                <div class="span4">
                                    <h3 class="heading">Qualifications</h3>
                                    <ol>
                                        <ui:repeat var="qualification"
                                            value="#{professionalDetailsManagedBean.professionalBean.professionalQualificationMap.entrySet().toArray()}">
                                            <li><h:commandLink styleClass="topopup_mini"
                                                    value="#{qualification.value.universityName}, #{qualification.value.degree}, #{qualification.value.stream}">
                                                </h:commandLink>&nbsp; <h:commandLink styleClass="btn btn-mini btn-primary">
                                                    <span class="icon-pencil"></span>
                                                </h:commandLink>&nbsp; <h:commandLink styleClass="btn btn-mini btn-warning">
                                                    <span class="icon-close"></span>
                                                </h:commandLink></li>
                                        </ui:repeat>
                                    </ol>
                                    <div>
                                        <a href="#" id="addEduQuals"
                                            class="btn btn-success pull-left topopup1"><i
                                            class="icon-plus"></i> Add Education Qualification</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="span3">
                            <h3 class="heading">Board Seats</h3>
                            <h4>Current :</h4>
                            <ul>
                                <ui:repeat var="board"
                                    value="#{professionalDetailsManagedBean.professionalBean.boardSeatsMap.entrySet().toArray()}">
                                    <h:panelGroup rendered="#{board.value.status}">
                                        <li><h:commandLink styleClass="topopup4">#{board.value.firmOrPortfolioName}
                                            </h:commandLink>&nbsp; <h:commandLink styleClass="btn btn-mini btn-primary">
                                                <span class="icon-pencil"></span>
                                            </h:commandLink>&nbsp; <h:commandLink styleClass="btn btn-mini btn-warning">
                                                <span class="icon-close"></span>
                                            </h:commandLink></li>
                                    </h:panelGroup>
                                </ui:repeat>
                            </ul>

                            <h4>Past :</h4>
                            <ul>
                                <ui:repeat var="board"
                                    value="#{professionalDetailsManagedBean.professionalBean.boardSeatsMap.entrySet().toArray()}">
                                    <h:panelGroup rendered="#{!board.value.status}">
                                        <li><h:commandLink styleClass="topopup4">#{board.value.firmOrPortfolioName}
                                            </h:commandLink>&nbsp; <h:commandLink styleClass="btn btn-mini btn-primary">
                                                <span class="icon-pencil"></span>
                                            </h:commandLink>&nbsp; <h:commandLink styleClass="btn btn-mini btn-warning">
                                                <span class="icon-close"></span>
                                            </h:commandLink></li>
                                    </h:panelGroup>
                                </ui:repeat>
                            </ul>
                            <div>
                                <a href="#" id="addbordseats"
                                    class="btn btn-success pull-left topopup2"><i
                                    class="icon-plus"></i> Add Board Seats</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </h:form>
            </section>
            </div>
        </div>
        </section>
        <!-- </h:form> -->
    </div>

</h:body>
</html>
```

ProfessionalDetailsManagedBean.Java:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class ProfessionalDetailsManagedBean extends PaginationManagedBean
        implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static Logger logger = Logger
            .getLogger(ProfessionalDetailsManagedBean.class);

    private static final int DEFAULT_PAGE_INDEX = 1;

    public ProfessionalBean professionalBean;

    public ProfessionalDetailsManagedBean() {
        super(DEFAULT_RECORDS_NUMBER, DEFAULT_PAGE_INDEX);
    }

    /**
     * @return the professionalBean
     */
    public ProfessionalBean getProfessionalBean() {
        return professionalBean;
    }

    /**
     * @param professionalBean
     *            the professionalBean to set
     */
    public void setProfessionalBean(ProfessionalBean professionalBean) {
        this.professionalBean = professionalBean;
    }

    public String updateProfessionalDetails() throws Exception {
        if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            logger.debug("Updating professional details: joinDate"
                    + this.professionalBean.getJoinDate() + ", exitDate: "
                    + this.professionalBean.getExitDate());
        }
        // Now updating the professional details in the db
        IProfessionalOperations professionalOperations = new ProfessionalOperationsImpl();
        professionalOperations
                .updatePortfolioProfessional(this.professionalBean);
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: I see that using JSF has got lot of disadvantages than advantages, it is decreasing the developers productivity with unknown issues. Solving one issue is leading to other issue and is becoming very tedious. Look at the similar issues list and there are no answers and I am facing the same issue and looks like there no working solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Code is working after removing the enctype in h:form. Also, removed the tags responsible for file upload. Moved all the file upload tags to a different h:form.

It is just a workaround, need to see how we can make it work with mime content.